# Update xml attribute values using xmlStarlet

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Student xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TrainingPOCs/SharedRec/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
  <Phno type="kwh" value="70" name=""/>
  <Phno type="wh" value="100" name="80">
    <Type>D</Type>
    <Mobile>7777777777</Mobile>
    <TPhone>6666666666</TPhone>
  </Phno>
  <Phno type="kwh" value="200" name="">
    <Type>E</Type>
    <Mobile>5555555555</Mobile>
    <TPhone>4444444444</TPhone>
  </Phno
</Student>
```

My input file
need to update name attribute with value attribute value wherever type attribute has kWh  Scripts i worked on

```
xmlstarlet edit -N w="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TrainingPOCs/SharedRec/Schemas/Schema.xsd" -u "/w:Student/w:Phno[@type='kwh']/@name" -x "/w:Student/w:Phno[@type='kwh']/@value" sample.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there but use a relative XPath expression for the
`-x / --expr` option:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
    -N w='http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TrainingPOCs/SharedRec/Schemas/Schema.xsd' \
    -u '/w:Student/w:Phno[@type="kwh"]/@name' \
    -x 'string(../@value)' file.xml
```

Alternatively, using the the default namespace
[shortcut](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html),

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -u '/_:Student/_:Phno[@type="kwh"]/@name' -x 'string(../@value)' file.xml
```

and perhaps adding an `-L / --inplace` option (see
[xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt))
for in-place editing.

Comment: Thank you so much @urcodebetterznow it's working well now.